# How to count value in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JavaScript, I'm trying get count monthly wise user count.

ex:      Jan March
   Mary   2   1
   Paul   1   1
   moth   1   1
people = [{name: 'Mary', course:’.Net’, Date:’1/6/2016’},{name: 'Paul', course:’.Net’, Date:’1/6/2016’},{name: 'Mary', course:’java’, Date:’5/16/2016’},{name: 'moth', course:’.Net’, Date:’1/6/2016’},{name: 'Paul', course:’jlava’, Date:’3/10/2016’},{name: 'moth', course:’java’, Date:’5/25/2016’},{name: 'Mary', course:’.Net’, Date:’3/20/2016’},{name: 'moth', course:’.Net’, Date:’1/6/2016’},{name: 'Mary', course:’.Net’, Date:’1/6/2016’}]

could you please let me know the script?

Comment: 1) Format correctly 2) We don't write code for you. This isn't a coding service.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:

1. Think about a data structure, how the result should look like.

   I suggest to use an object for it, because this is for grouping an easy access structure.

   > ```
   > {
   >     "Mary": {
   >         "2016-1": 2,
   >         "2016-5": 1,
   >         "2016-3": 1
   >     },
   >     "Paul": {
   >         "2016-1": 1,
   >         "2016-3": 1
   >     },
   >     "moth": {
   >         "2016-1": 2,
   >         "2016-5": 1
   >     }
   > }
   > ```
2. Select an apropriate method to iterate the give array, like [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). This method offers a visit of every item in the array.

   1. Split the date for getting year and month for grouping.
   2. Build a new string as date key.
   3. Assign an object to the property with the actual name in the object, if not already there.
   4. Check if a property with the date exist and increment it.
3. Use the obejct for further action.